# unescaping xml text from ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, decoding, elementtree

I'm trying to pull out an escape noded from an XML document.  The raw text for the node looks like this:

```
<Notes>{&quot;Phase&quot;: 0, &quot;Flipper&quot;: 0, &quot;Guide&quot;: 0,     
&quot;Sample&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle8&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle5&quot;: 0,     
&quot;Triangle4&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle7&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle6&quot;: 0,     
&quot;Triangle1&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle3&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle2&quot;: 0}</Notes>
```

I'm pulling the text out as follows:

```
infile = ET.parse("C:/userfiles/EXP011/SESAME_60/SESAME_60_runinfo.xml")
r = infile.getroot()
XMLNS = "{http://example.com/foo/bar/runinfo_v4_3}"
x=r.find(".//"+XMLNS+"Notes")
print(x.text)
```

I expected to get:

```
{"Phase": 0, "Flipper": 0, "Guide&quot": 0,     
"Sample": 0, "Triangle8": 0, "Triangle5": 0,     
"Triangle4": 0, "Triangle7": 0, "Triangle6": 0,     
"Triangle1": 0, "Triangle3": 0, "Triangle2": 0}
```

but, instead, I got:

```
 {&quot;Phase&quot;: 0, &quot;Flipper&quot;: 0, &quot;Guide&quot;: 0,      
 &quot;Sample&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle8&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle5&quot;: 0,   
 &quot;Triangle4&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle7&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle6&quot;: 0, 
 &quot;Triangle1&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle3&quot;: 0, &quot;Triangle2&quot;: 0}
```

How do I get the unescaped string?

Comment: ElementTree does not unescape `&quot;` because you normally don't *need* to escape `"` in XML. My answer was wrong for the same reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `HTMLParser.HTMLParser()`:

```
In [8]: import HTMLParser    

In [11]: HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape('&quot;')
Out[11]: u'"'
```

saxutils handles `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`, but it does not handle `&quot;`.

```
In [9]: import xml.sax.saxutils as saxutils

In [10]: saxutils.unescape('&quot;')
Out[10]: '&quot;'
```

Comment: Quite correct; `"` does not *need* to be quoted in XML, so the saxutils module doesn't deal with that (just like ElementTree).

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  Someday I'll have to talk with the server devs and find out why the server is escaping the quotes in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Since `python 3.4` you can use `html.unescape`.

```
>>> from html import unescape
>>> unescape('&quot;')
'"'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not managed to use escape for `&quot;` in Python `2.7.5` for some reason but I found a workaround to get " instead of `&quot;` in XML file using the `replace` function as below:

```py
with open(xmlfilename, 'w') as f:
     f.write(myxml.toprettyxml().replace("&quot;",'"'))
```